# function call in node js using socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to call a function which is created in another "class", and I want to use it in the socket.on (...) but it is not working , it keeps showing

this.function is not a function.

here is the code

```
//calling the function 

 Serveur.prototype.traitementSurConnection = function(socket) {
var that = this
    socket.on('connection', function (creator, typeArtifact,idConteneur, typeConteneur) {

        that.addArtifact('momo', 'img', 1,0);

    })
};

//the function

ZoneCollaborative.prototype.addArtifact = function(creator, typeArtifact,idConteneur, typeConteneur) {

    // calcul d'un nouvel identifiant

    var id = this.setIdAr();

    console.log('    *** ZC : calcul nouveau IdArtifact = '+id);


    // création de l'artifact

    var monArtifact = new Artifact(id, creator, typeArtifact, idConteneur,

            typeConteneur);

    console.log('    *** ZC : creation artifact'+monArtifact.getId() );

    // ajout à la liste

    this.artifacts.push(monArtifact);


    console.log('    *** ZC : total artifact ='+ this.artifacts.length);

};
```

Comment: Post more code for Serveur instance creation and usage.

Comment: Do `Serveur` and `ZoneCollaborative` share the prototype? Can you post the code where this happens?

Comment: no they don't share it

Answer (score 0):

here is the ful code of bothe Serveur.js and ZoneCollaborative.js

//Serveur.js

```
    var http = require('http');

var socket = require('socket.io');

var ZP = require('./ZonePartage');

var Constantes = require('./Constante');

//création des constantes

var CONSTANTE = new Constantes();

function Serveur(ZP, port) {

    this.ZP = ZP;

    this.port = port;

    console.log("    ---- Creation d'un serveur pour la ZP (" + ZP.getId()
            + ") sur le port " + port);

    var serveur = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    });

    serveur.listen(this.port, function() {

        console.log('    ---- Server en ecoute sur port ' + port);

    });

    //

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(serveur);


    console.log('    ---- Socket en ecoute sur port ' + port);

    browser = require('iotdb-arp');// module qui s'occupe de la determination de l'adress MAC

    io.sockets.on('connection', (function(socket) {

        console.log('    ---- Socket connection');
        console.log('un utilisateur est connecté');

        browser.browser({}, function(error, d) {

            if (error) {

                console.log("#", error);

            } else if (d) {

                var adresse = d.ip;

                console.log('son adresse ip est ' + adresse); //obtenir l'adress ip de l'utilisateur connecté 

            }
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {

            console.log(' ==> 1 utilisateur déconnecté <== '); //déconnection 
        });

        this.traitementSurConnection(socket);

    }).bind(this));

    console.log('    ---- Socket en attente de traitement port ' + port);
}

module.exports = Serveur;



Serveur.prototype.demandConnexion = function(idZEP) {

    if (this.ZP.createZE(idZEP))

    {

        console.log(' ==> socket : demande de creation ZE pour ' + idZEP
                + ' accepte');

    }

    else

    {

        console.log(' ==> socket : demande de creation ZE pour ' + idZEP
                + ' refuse');

    }

};

Serveur.prototype.traitementSurConnection = function(socket) {
    console.log(' ==> socket connexion');

    var self = this;
    socket.on('connection', function(creator, typeArtifact, idConteneur,
            typeConteneur) {

        self.addArtifact('momo', 'img', 1, 0);

    })

          }
    });
```

//ZoneCollaborative.js

```
ZoneCollaborative.prototype.addArtifact = function(creator, typeArtifact,idConteneur, typeConteneur) {



    // calcul d'un nouvel identifiant

    var id = this.setIdAr();

    console.log('    *** ZC : calcul nouveau IdArtifact = '+id);


    // création de l'artifact

    var monArtifact = new Artifact(id, creator, typeArtifact, idConteneur,

            typeConteneur);

    console.log('    *** ZC : creation artifact'+monArtifact.getId() );

    // ajout à la liste

    this.artifacts.push(monArtifact);


    console.log('    *** ZC : total artifact ='+ this.artifacts.length);

    };
```